# EXC_BAD_ACCESS pointer C++

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers

This is by far the most frustrating error I have come across while programming in C++. Here is the code I am trying to run. Every time I run it, it gives me bad access error and when I try to debug it with LLDB, it shows that value of every member in end = 0 and gives the bad access pointer error. Please let me know what's the solution to the current problem. I have been stuck on this for a while now and I come across this error every now and then so any debugging tips would be appreciated.

```
struct edge;
struct node
{
  int id;
  double longitude;
  double latitude;
  double distance;
  string state;
  string name;
  vector<edge*>r;
  int prio;
};
struct edge
{
  string name, type;
  double dist;
  node* x;
  node* y;
  void print()
  {
    cout << name << " " << type << " "<< dist << " miles" << " from " << x->id << " to " << y->id << endl;
  }
  edge(node* x, node* y, double dist, string name)
  {
    this->x = x;
    this->y = y;
    this->dist = dist;
    this->name = name;
  }
  edge(){};
};
struct route{
  int place1;
  int place2;
  string rt;
  string vert;
  double lengt;

  route(int o, int d, double l,string r ){
    place1 = o;
    place2 = d;
    rt =r;
    lengt=l;
  }
};
struct compPair
{
  bool operator()(node* a, node* b)
  {
    return a->prio > b->prio;
  }
};
void SPT(vector<node*> & g, int from, int to){
  priority_queue <node *, vector<node*>, compPair> pq;
  g[from]->prio = 0;
  pq.push(g[from]);

  while(!pq.empty()){
    node* place1 = pq.top();pq.pop();
    for(int i=0;i<place1->r.size();i++){
      edge* rd = place1->r[i];
      node* place2 = rd->x;
      if(place2==place1){
        place2=rd->y;
      }
      if(place2->prio == -2){
        place2->prio = place1->prio + rd->dist;
        pq.push(place2);
      }
      else if (place2->prio > (place1->prio + rd->dist)){
        place2->prio = place1->prio + rd->dist;
      }
    }
  }

  node* beg = g[from];
  node* end = g[to];

  if(g[from]->prio < 0 || g[to]->prio < 0){
    cout <<"Path does not exist";
    return;
  }
//THIS IS BUGGY CODE, everything works fine without this code //
  node* lowp = end;
  vector <route*> p;
  while(beg!=end){
    double reallowp = end->prio;
    edge* rtt = end->r[0];
    for(int i =0;i<end->r.size();i++){
      edge *r = end->r[i];
      node* town1 = r->x;
      if(town1 == end){
        town1 = r->y;
      }
      if(town1->prio <= reallowp){
        reallowp = town1->prio;
        lowp = town1;
        rtt = r;
      }
    }

    route* e = new route(end->id,lowp->id,rtt->dist,rtt->name);

    p.push_back(e);
    end=lowp;
  }


  for(int i=p.size()-1;i>=0;i--){
    cout << "From intersection " << p[i]->place2 << "take " << p[i]->rt << " " << p[i]->lengt << " miles to intersection " << p[i]->place1 << endl;
  }

}
int main()
{
  vector<node*>t = readTown();
  readRoad(t);
  SPT(t,68,69);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It is recommended that in the question is a minimal and reproducible problem as this is much easier to debug (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Basically, post enough code so that I can copy and paste, compile, and see the error myself, as right now there is no definition of "node", no main() function, no function definitions that are required, etc. so I have no way of knowing the issue.

Comment: @RealPawPaw Sorry, I have updated the code. Please try to look for the issue now. Really frustrated by this error. Thanks.

Comment: You didn't include the read functions. But anyway, the likely answer is that your indexes are out of bounds. Use vector's at(index) function instead of operator[] to catch that. Or you somehow loaded up an empty pointer during read. You might be better off using shared_ptr or unique_ptr instead of raw pointers here.

Comment: There is an incredible number of pointers used and vector of pointers, yet I see not a single allocation or sufficient number of *address of* operators used to support all of the pointers used. Using pointers is fine, but they must each point to a valid object with valid storage. It appears that is where your code is breaking down. I would suggest a visit to [**How to debug small programs**](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and your emphasis in your line-by-line analysis should be "What valid object does this pointer point to?"

Comment: Would you clarify the meaning of the comment in your code "THIS IS BUGGY CODE, everything works fine without this code"?

Comment: You are possibly changing priorities of nodes while they sit inside priority queue. This exhibits undefined behavior; the priority queue builds its data structures based on the relative order of the elements, and you are changing that order from under the queue behind its back, breaking those data structures. In other words, the queue reasonably assumes that the value of `compPair()(A, B)` doesn't change as long as `A` and `B` are in the queue; but your code does cause it to change.

Comment: The "BUGGY CODE" loop may visit towns that weren't visited by the search, and have negative `prio`. That loop in fact prefers such towns (`town1->prio <= reallowp` condition favors negative `prio`), and so will go off the charted route, and possibly walk forever in circles.